# run javascript functions when user clicks link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I only want this bit of code to fire when a link is clicked on

```
<a href="#" id="open">OPEN</a>

$( window ).resize(function() {
    resetValue();
    sizeScrollbar();
    reflowContent();
});
//init scrollbar size
setTimeout( sizeScrollbar, 10 );//safari wants a timeout
```

So in theory, I want:

```
if(open button clicked)
{

  $( window ).resize(function() {
    resetValue();
    sizeScrollbar();
    reflowContent();
  });
  //init scrollbar size
  setTimeout( sizeScrollbar, 10 );//safari wants a timeout
}
```

I know how to do it in jquery, but this code is in a separate js file (filename: scroll.js) that I include in the footer.

I tried commenting out

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
   resetValue();
   sizeScrollbar();
   reflowContent();
});
//init scrollbar size
setTimeout( sizeScrollbar, 10 );//safari wants a timeout
```

And firing it in my main.js file like so:

```
$(".open").click(function() {

    $( window ).resize(function() {
      resetValue();
      sizeScrollbar();
      reflowContent();
    });
    //init scrollbar size
    setTimeout( sizeScrollbar, 10 );//safari wants a timeout

});
```

But it gives me an error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: sizeScrollbar is not defined

I assume that is because I am trying to call sizeScrollbar outside of the scroll.js file when I am calling it in the main.js file.

Comment: In what order do you include the two JS files?

Comment: add a code, where you define sizeScrollbar function

Comment: @Trojan scroll.js then main.js, jquery and jquery ui files are above scroll and main.

Comment: you can use sizeScrollbar in click-function as callback function

Comment: @msangel could you provide some clarification?

Comment: Try using `$(function () { /*CODE*/ })`

Comment: @EduardoCuomo could you provide it as an answer with the code I have above?

Comment: Also, you keep rebinding a listener to the `window`'s `resize` event on each and every `click`... I'm confident you don't actually want to do that. Do you perhaps want to set a flag on the `click` instead, and then have your `resize` handler check the flag before firing its methods?

Comment: @user2167382 could you provide an answer explaining that?

Comment: @Brad, you have error `Uncaught ReferenceError: sizeScrollbar is not defined`, so it might that your function is not visible due to scope of declaration(in inner function and not visible to global scope)

Comment: @msangel yes, I figured that was the case, how would I go about getting the code I want wrapped within the click event of the open link

Comment: Can you please show us what scroll.js looks like? Mainly I'm interested in how you declared sizeScrollbar() (is it inside a closure? Is it attached to the global namespace? etc.). This will affect how you can call it.

Comment: @straker scroll.js https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8964059

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that scroll.js is declared inside a closure ( $(function() { }); ). If you want anything you've declared inside the closure made available, you must return something at the end of the closure. This means you'll probably want to return an object that has your functions in it:

```
// scroll.js
var scroll = (function() {

   // code       

   function sizeScrollbar() {};

   // code

   return {
      'sizeScrollbar' : sizeScrollbar
   }

})();
```

then in main.js you can call sizeScrollbar like so:

```
scroll.sizeScrollbar();
```

Comment: this should be in the main.js or scroll.js file?

Comment: the return has to happen at the end of scroll.js if you want something available in main.js

Comment: this code is bloken, it will assign to global scope result of first running of this function (as far as i understand)

Comment: // change function call to function name (or use my answer ;) )

Comment: @straker, `return { 'sizeScrllbar' : sizeScrollbar()  } ` wil call function once and assing result to `sizeScrllbar` as to variable, but not function

Comment: and if use this answer, there also need change `setTimeout( sizeScrollbar, 10 )` to `setTimeout( scroll.sizeScrollbar, 10 )`, so my answer is easier to implement

Comment: I tried this and it gave me the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Object function scroll() { [native code] } has no method 'sizeScrollbar' https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8964378

Comment: @Brad sorry, missed the ending `()` at the end. Need to invoke the function to return the object.

Comment: @msangel it is true that your answer is easier to implement, but overall it is considered bad JavaScript practice to declare functions or variables directly to the global scope. It really depends on your coding style in the end I guess. https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#variables